# Server doesn't listen outside of Docker

Tags: docker, sockets

I created a docker Image for the Server side on Windows 7 after i launched the container(server) i checked using the command prompt if the port is listening (`netstat -an`) the port is not listening. How can I make the server listen outside of docker in windows?

Without listening to server from outside I cant have access to container(server) from other host machine in the same subnet network.
When i repeat the same process in Ubuntu 18.04 it works fine and the port is listening as bellow:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

the command i used to start the container is:

```
 run -it -p 8000:8000 server:latest
```

server.py

```
import socket
import time
import pickle
HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))  
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    d = {1:"hello", 2: "world"}
    msg = pickle.dumps(d)
    msg = bytes(f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}", 'utf-8')+msg
    print(msg)
    clientsocket.send(msg)
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
COPY test /test/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "test/server.py"]
#CMD ["python", "test/client.py"]
```

Inside the docker :

```
$ docker port server
8000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and the default network "bridge" is used in docker

Comment: I would enable telnet and try `telnet localhost 8000` from host

Comment: When you try to access it you make sure that you are hitting the local ip eg(`192.168.x.x:8000`)?

Comment: When i use  `telnet  localhost 8000`  could not open conection but with `telnet  Docker machine IP 8000`  it opens connection.How to make the connection  from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The Docker daemon doesn't run native on Windows, which means it runs in a separate virtual machine (VirtualBox, Hyper-V, etc.). You need to find out what you are using and then adjust the settings of the VM to forward traffic from host (8080) to the VM (8080). Only then your Windows host will be able to actually communicate with the container.

Comment: I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows 7 ,do you have a way to forward traffic from Docker to localhost?

Comment: Behind the scenes it uses VirtualBox or Hyper-V. Do you know which one your machine uses?